# Array of Images ReactJs responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, carousel, image-rendering

I am just getting started with web pages. I am trying to make a function for the react responsive carousel so I can pass an array of images and it renders depending on the number of images, I've been trying to run something like this:

**Callingfun.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Carouselfun from '../components/Carouselfun'

import webs from '../assets/images/proj/website.JPG'
import webs1 from '../assets/images/proj/website1.JPG'
import webs2 from '../assets/images/proj/website2.JPG'


const imagess= [webs,webs1,webs2];

function WebsitePage(props) {
    return(
        <div className="g-background-pages">
            
            <Carouselfun   
                        imag={imagess}
                        />
        </div>
    );

}

export default WebsitePage;
```

**Carouselfun.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Jumbotron, Container, Row, Col, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';


function carouselfun(props){
    
    return(
        <Jumbotron>
            <Container>
                 <Row>
                    <div>
                        <div>        
                            <Carousel>
                             
                            {props.imag}.forEach(element => {
                                <div>
                                <Image src= element/>
                                </div>
                            });
                                
                            </Carousel>         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
    )
}

export default carouselfun;
```

Is there something wrong in the way I am passing my arrays of Images?
or  does it have to be with the render function?

Thank you

Comment: <Image src= element/> ?   It should be  <Image src={element}/>

Comment: it should be like this:  {props.imag.map((element, index) =>
                                <div key=\`image at ${index}\`>
                                <Image src= element/>
                                </div>)}

Comment: I've tried that, but I get the error
[ 'element' is not defined  no-undef ] @TalmacelMarianSilviu

Comment: The second answer doesn't work either,
I get [ Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text ] for the element part

Comment: sorry can you try this? {props.imag.map((element, index) => (
        <div key={\`image at ${index}\`}>
          <Image src={element} />
        </div>
      ))}

Comment: It worked! just pass element like {element} 
 {props.imag.map((element, index) => <div key=`image at ${index}`> <Image src= {element}/> </div>)}
Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using array.forEach, where a array.map operation will do instead. Map will transform your array and return an array of `<div><Image src={element}/> </div>` (ReactNodes). Foreach wont return anything. As Talmacel notes in the comment you were missing some brackets too.